# Precision in FILTER() for DateTime

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax

I want to do a Dax funtion to filter a data based on DateTime values but with a precision of 15 minutes.
How could i do that ?

```
FILTER(MarketSales;(CompanyX[Date] < (MarketSales[Date] - 15) || CompanyX[Date] > (MarketSales[Date] - 15))
```

How could i precise 15 minutes and not 15 days ? Or is there any other way to do that ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

you can do the following:

```
FILTER(MarketSales;(CompanyX[Date] < (MarketSales[Date] - TIME(0,15,0)) || CompanyX[Date] > (MarketSales[Date] - TIME(0,15,0)))
```

I copied your DAX formula but I think that you should check the first argument of your formula. I think you should use a '+' instead of '-'. But that is only my guess.
Hope it helps you.

Comment: Yes you are right, my mistake, and Thank you my buddy